# How to checkout commits in detached head

Tags: git

I had 2 commits in a detatched head. I tried to checkout master, in order to branch it and add the new commits, and now the 2 commits are gone. Is there any way to retrieve them?

the tree was :

commit a -> commit b master

commit a -> commit c -> commit d HEAD

I want d back.

As instructed in other questions, I have gotten the SHA-1 of the "lost" commits with

```
git reflog
```

How can I create a branch in a, and merge the 2 commits? Do I check out 'commit a' branch, and use merge with the SHA-1 of 'commit d' (the latest commit in the detatched head)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the SHA of *commit d*, you can create a new branch pointing to it by doing:

```
git branch new_branch thesha
```

Comment: Thanks, I panicked so much. XD